# V-Select Change not Triggering Class Change Parent Component (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a form that I'm displaying custom v-cards that have v-selects on them. Any time the focus is on a v-card, or any of the input/selects/elements within it, I would like to have a blue border displayed along the left side of the v-card. When you focus or click on one of the v-cards, or elements within them, the border shows up. So far this mostly works.

If I click a v-select, the drop down dialog shows, and the border stays/shows, but once I select an item in the v-select and the dialog goes away, so does the border(and the focus remains on the v-select). The border is triggered by boolean "selectedElement". I've tried adding **@change="selected=true"** to the v-select, which in theory should mean that after selecting an item in the drop down, the boolean should be true and trigger/show the border (added as a class on the v-card). Is vue redrawing before the boolean trigger is changed?

I have tried setting initiating a click event:

```
this.$refs.parentComp.$el.click();
this.$refs.parentComp.click();
setTimeout(() => {this.$refs.parentComp.$el.click()})
```

I've tried to set the focus on the parent element:

```
this.$refs.parentComp.$el.focus();
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Before selection:
[image]

After selecting the bottom v-card:
[image]

Also related - I removed the ripple from the v-card, how do I remove the gray overlay when clicking on it?

**formElementeditor.vue**

```
<template>
<v-card 
  elevation="2" 
  class="mb-5"
  :class="[selected ? 'selectedElement' : '']"
  @click="selected = true"
  v-click-outside="elemClickedOff"
  :ripple="false"
  ref="parentComp"
>
  
          <v-select
          v-model="localType"
          @change="selected = true" // also tried @change="updateFocus()"
          :items="options"
          item-text="type"
          item-value="type"
          label="Form Element Type"
          outlined
          dense
          hideDetails
          >
          <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
            <v-icon class="mr-2">
              {{item.icon}}
            </v-icon>
            {{item.type}}
          </template>
          <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
            <v-icon class="mr-2">
              {{item.icon}}
            </v-icon>
            {{item.type}}
          </template>
            <!-- <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-icon>
                <v-icon>
                  {{item.icon}}
                </v-icon>
              </v-list-item-icon>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>
                  {{item.type}}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item> -->
          </v-select>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="pb-2">
        <v-layout>
        <v-flex>
          <v-switch
            v-model="localRequired"
            color="red"
            hide-details
            class="mt-0"
            label="Required"
          ></v-switch>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex>
          <v-btn :disabled="disabled" @click.stop="delElem()" icon><v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon></v-btn>
          <v-btn @click.stop="addElem();elemClickedOff();" icon><v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon></v-btn>
        </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <template 
          v-else-if="localType=='Multiple Choice'"
          
          >
          <v-container>
            <!-- <v-slide-y-transition group> -->
              <v-row
                class="pb-0"
                dense
                v-for="(item, i) in this.localSubElementsArray"
                :key="item.id"
              >
                <v-col class="pb-2" cols="7" >
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Option"
                    outlined
                    dense
                    prepend-icon="mdi-radiobox-blank"
                    hideDetails
                  >
                    <!-- <template v-slot:append-outer>
                      <v-layout>
                        <v-flex>
                          <v-btn icon><v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon></v-btn>
                          <v-btn icon><v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon></v-btn>
                        </v-flex>
                      </v-layout>
                    </template> -->
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col class="pl-0" cols="2">
                  <v-layout>
                    <v-flex>
                      <v-btn @click="delSubElement(i)" icon><v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon></v-btn>
                      <v-btn @click="addSubElement(i)" icon><v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon></v-btn>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            <!-- </v-slide-y-transition> -->
          </v-container>
        </template>
       
  </v-row>
</v-card>
```

**script**

```
    <script>
  export default {
    name: "formelement",
    props:['loc','id','label', 'type', 'data', 'subElements', 'required'],
    data: () => ({
      localSubElementsArray: [],
      selected: true,
    }),
    methods: {
      elemClickedOff() {
        this.selected = false;
      },
      updateFocus() {
        //setTimeout(() => {this.$refs.parentComp.$el.focus()});
        this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.parentComp.$el.click());
        this.selected = true;
      },
    },
    created:function(){
        this.localSubElementsArray = this.subElements ?? [];
        if(this.localSubElementsArray.length == 0)
          this.addSubElement(null);
    },
  }
</script>
```

**style being applied**

```
<style scoped>
  .selectedElement {
    border-left: 3px solid var(--v-primary-base);

  }
</style>
```

Comment: It appears the v-click-outside="elemClickedOff" directive is running after the click event on the v-dialog in the v-select. I'm not sure how to prevent clicking on a v-select item in its dialog from causing the v-click-outside from firing, (I need that directive in place or some version of it).

Comment: Update - fixed this problem by changing the way I was handling this. Rather than handling this in the sub component, I handled it in the parent component and synced the attribute/prop and then emit when I select a component. This works regardless of the click events and input types on the subcomponent.

Comment: Also using @click.native="elemSelected()" on the v-card eliminated the ripple effect and gray overlay while still calling the elemSelected() method.